# Create a new region within an existing one

Tags: theming, 7

I want to create a new region within an existing region which is by default or is custom made. I have created a custom region called footer_top. I want to create a new region within this region, i.e, a nested region. What should i do...what code should i write in page.tpl.php and how?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to have nested region? I think you could simply have three regions instead, rendered in that order.

Comment: @SGhosh...i just want to learn

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [region.tpl.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!region.tpl.php/7)

And add a [template_preprocess_region](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_region/7) to add the new region variable with in this region.

You can use the following code to add the region variable to the region.tpl.php

```
$variables['custom'] = block_get_blocks_by_region('custom');
```

So the over all process would be as follows.

first you would create a preprocess_region function as given below

```
function theme_name_preprocess_region(&$variables) {
  $variables['region_name'] = block_get_blocks_by_region('region_name');
}
```

next you would create a region template file called region--region_name.tpl.php

and print the variable `$variables['region_name'];`

Comment: So this will print another region inside one region. Both regions will be available in the blocks page for placing blocks right?